# Query run time in Lucene and index size

Tags: search, solr, elasticsearch, lucene

I have heard that, in Lucene, processing time per query & memory used barely depends on the **size of the index**.  Instead, I have been told, the **size of the query** itself is really what determines the time and computational resources it takes to run the query. The argument that I have been given comes down to  *that's just because of how **reverse indexing** works*.

I'm not that familiar with Lucene, but what is exactly the basis for this assertion, and how much truth is there in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both the index and the query have a role in resource usage. Lucene builds a reverse index based on the list of the documents - which words are in which documents. The reverse index will grow with the index (admittedly, you can probably find edge cases where this is not validated, but it will be true in any real-life, practical case).

As for the query, it lists conditions that have to be validated for the documents to be returned - again (generally speaking) the more conditions, the more resource usage.

So the answer is definitely both - size of the index and size of the query contribute to resource usage.

Answer (score 2):

Lucene indexes the full text and store links from `terms` to their documents. While searching the `terms`, lucene searches the index instead of actual documents. That is why it is called `inverted index` and provides fast responses.

Lucene uses immutable lists (array type) data structure for storing the term dictionary. All the search query fetch the documents based on the information found in term dictionary. Lucene cache the term dictionary using a FST data structure implementation, which is essentially an implementation of Trie data structure. In FST, lucene store the term information based on the prefixes and their offset in the term dictionary. From there, it perform a sequential comparison for matching the search query. Once match is found in the term dictionary, it provides contains other information like frequency and offset for the document posting list. The posting list essentially contains the memory offset to the actual documents.

For example you are searching for a term: `lucene` then how the FST look like and sequential search in term dictionary. The terms in Term Dictionary are sorted.

[image: Lucene FST structure]

[image: Lucene term dictionary]

`Conclusion:` Lucene requires two disk seeks for searching terms per field from the search query. 1st seek, with the offset from in-memory FST to Term Dictionary and 2nd seek, offset to the posting lists to find all the matching documents offsets. Then it requires only 1 disk seek to serve each of the matched document.

The processing time and memory uses becomes bottleneck when index size grow then the size of memory (cache) available. Which is why concept of sharding comes into picture. You distribute your document among many shards so that size of the index will be small and could be cache in-memory.

Comment: Thanks, while this is informative, I'm not sure how it answers the question.

Comment: Initially I talked about how search is done in lucene. I tried to link it with them memory uses and processing time while querying. please check again. Thanks for your feedback.